# How can i create page through plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am developing WordPress plugin.This plugin has own login system.Which means users can register into the system. Then they can login. if the user login, i want to redirect them to their own profile page.This page should not be accessible while user is in logout or plugin 
is in inactive.So how can i create page through plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the page needs to be added and available on the front end, you can use [wp_insert_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) to create the page, the use a conditional to only display it if the user is logged in:

`if(is_user_logged_in()) { // display content }`